# AJAX example in magento

Tags: ajax, magento-1.9

Hello everyone,

I am a newbie to Magento. I want to learn **ajax process in Magento.** Can anyone help me to understand ajax in Magento with one simple example?
Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I give you a simple example for you. To work with basic jQuery Ajax in Magento you have work in phtml page and Controller. 
Just add the script in phtml page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".like-result").click(function() {
            //alert(this.id);
            var id = this.id;
            //alert(custid);
            jQuery(".notify-status").hide();
            jQuery(".notify-loader").show();
            jQuery.ajax({      
            type: "POST",
            data: 'pid=' + id,
            url:'http://192.168.2.3/subhranil-demo/blog/index/likecount',
            success:function(response){                       
                if (response) {
                    jQuery(".notify-loader").hide();
                    jQuery(".notify-status").show();
                    jQuery("#un"+id).html(response);
                }
            }
            });
        });
     });
</script>
```

In the above script under jQuery.ajax you can also see type, data, url. type is used for sending process like POST or GET; in data, you will send information to the controller; in URL, you can declare the controller path. Here I have a 'blog' module and I write the public function under 'index' controller and I give the function name 'likecount'. Also here my base path is http://192.168.2.3/subhranil-demo/. So I add the link to URL as following structure: http://192.168.2.3/subhranil-demo/blog/index/likecount.
Now I go to 'IndexController.php' in my controller's folder of blog module and open it. Under the class I add the following function:

```
public function likecountAction()
    {
    $blogload = Mage::getModel('blog/blog')->load($_POST['pid']);
    $newid = $blogload['like']+1;
    $data = array('like'=> $newid);
    $blogload->addData($data);
    try {
        $blogload->setId($_POST['pid'])->save();
        echo $newid;

    } catch (Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage(); 
    }
    }
```

Here in the Blog Database, I have the fields like pid (as a primary key) and like. the function works like that when you click on 'like-result' class the like increase +1. 
My div structure also like that:

```
<?php

    $allCollection=Mage::getModel("blog/blog")->getCollection();
    $allCollection->addFieldToFilter('status',1);
    if ($allCollection->count() >= 1)
    {
        $news = array();
        ?>
        <div class="blog clearfix">
        <?php
        foreach ($allCollection as $news)
        {?>   
<p class="like-result" id="<?php echo $news->getId(); ?>"> <?php echo $news->getLike(); ?> </p>
    <a style="display: none;" class="notify-loader"><img src="http://www.sendhersomething.com/skin/frontend/megatron/default/images/ajax/notify-loader.gif"></a>
    <a style="display: none;" class="notify-status"><img src="http://www.sendhersomething.com/skin/frontend/megatron/default/images/ajax/ststus.png"></a>
  <?php } ?>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Try this!